# Detectar partes de uma string

Tags: javascript

Olá, essa é a minha primeira vez no stackoverflow, e estou com uma dificuldade, preciso saber como posso detectar partes de uma string, exemplo:

```
String: "Definir a altura de %s para %d"
```

e quero as informações *%s* e *%d*

Exemplo:

```
"Definir a altura de objeto para 500"
```

Saída:

```
Saída: "objeto", 500
```

Há alguma forma de obter isso? OBS: a saída não precisa ser obrigatoriamente em algum tipo de dado, pode ser saída em 2 variáveis, 1 array ou qualquer coisa.

OBS: Linguagem Javascript.

Obrigado.

Comment: Você quer procurar uma determinada palavra dentro de uma frase e capturar ela?

Comment: Na verdade não,
Eu preciso de uma informação que eu não tenho, que pode ser variada, similar a uma entrada formatada

Comment: as informações serão sempre no mesmo lugar? Se for, pode criar uma função e passar dois parâmetros, assim preenchendo eles no devido lugar da string e depois retornar a mesma.

Comment: serão no mesmo lugar, mas eu recebo a string completa do usuário nessa situação:
Usuário: "Definir a altura de objeto para 500"
Código retorna: "objeto", 500

Comment: Será sempre essa mesma frase?

Comment: nessa situação sim, mas eu vou colocar mais situações aplicando a mesma lógica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se a frase for sempre a mesma como você disse, pode fazer dessa forma:

```js
let phrase = "Definir a altura de cadeira para 500";

//quebra a frase no primeiro "de"
let part1 = phrase.split(' de '); 
//quebra a frase no primeiro "para"
let part2 = part1[1].split(' para ')

console.log(part2[0])
console.log(part2[1])
```

Se quiser algo mais dinâmico, pode criar uma função aonde o primeiro parâmetro será a frase em si e os dois últimos serão os delimitadores para realizar a quebra da frase.

Exemplo:

```js
function getPhrase(phrase, param1, param2) {
    let phrases = phrase;    

    //quebra a frase no primeiro "de"
    let part1 = phrases.split(" "+param1+" "); 
    //quebra a frase no primeiro "para"
    let part2 = part1[1].split(" "+param2+" ")

    //console.log(part2[0])
    //console.log(part2[1])
    
    let result = [ {'1': part2[0].trim(), '2': part2[1].trim() }];
    
    return result;

}


$(document).ready(function(){
   let obj = getPhrase('Definir a altura de cadeira para 500', 'de', 'para');
   console.log(obj)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Lembrando que fiz os exemplos baseados em suas informações e que o código pode facilmente ser adaptado.

Comment: Muito obrigado!
Funcionou perfeitamente :D

Comment: Por nada amigo! :)

Comment: Mas se você está quebrando a frase no "de", o que acontece se a frase for algo como "Definir a altura de cadeira para 500"?

Comment: @Andre, bem observado. Editei a resposta, obrigado.

Answer (score 5):

Vou deixar uma solução mais segura usando expressões regulares, porque se "objeto" conter espaços, usar split poderá gerar erros.

```js
var frase = "Definir a altura de objeto para 500";
var objeto = frase.replace(/^Definir a altura de (.*) para (.*)$/, '$1');
var numero = frase.replace(/^Definir a altura de (.*) para (.*)$/, '$2');

console.log(objeto, numero);
```

Comment: ótimo método, mais seguro que o meu. Gosto de soluções com regex, embora não entender muito. +1

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função split, enviando um espaço vazio como separador, retornando um array.

Ex:

```
const frase = 'Definir a altura de objeto para 500';
frase.split(' '); 
// [ 'Definir', 'a', 'altura', 'de', 'objeto', 'para', '500' ]
```

Como um espaço vazio foi usado como separador, será retornado um array com todas as palavras da string.
Você poderá buscá-las pelo índice.

```
frase[4];
// objeto
```

Espero ter ajudado!